# How does Firebase work with PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to coding and I am very confused in terms of what Firebase can do for me. I don't know how it will integrate with my web application. 
My web application is going to be a ecommerce website and it will use the Algolia/Swiftype API, Stripe API and Google Maps. The website will also have 2 types of user accounts.

Just a couple of questions:

1) If I use Firebase, do I still need to use MySQL?

2) Do I need to design the Firebase database?

3) Will using Firebase speed up development time?

4) If I use Firebase, do I still need to use AWS or Rackspace?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. No you don't need MySQL if you are using Firebase. But, there are good reasons to use one or the other, or both together. They are very different in how they work and you need to evaluate them independently for your use cases.
2. Not necessarily, because Firebase is "schema-less", meaning it is based entirely on the JSON data you put into it. In essence, it's a massive JSON object you put data into. (But, I'm not saying you don't need a little planning to make things work right, I'm merely saying you don't need to plan all your data types, columns, etc.)
3. Maybe, maybe not. It depends on how familiar you are with JSON, working with schema-less data, and working with restful services. I would argue that it all depends on what you're trying to accomplish, and how complex your system is, as to whether it will speed things up or not.
4. No (but maybe yes). Are you building a Node application? If you're building in Node then you can do everything through Firebase (they can host it for you). If you are delivering the first byte in something else (like PHP), then you would need a different host like AWS or Rackspace. But, you'd always have Firebase hosting your data.

Hope those answers help! Please comment under this answer if you need any clarification.